# not able to change the orientation in a desired manner

Tags: android

i am changing my app to landscape on the click of a button but the problem is i have a list view and video view of a fixed height in portrait mode and after changing to landscape mode i only want to show the video view but videoview is shown of that height but i want to show it as full screen.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/relative2">
<VideoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/video"
    />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="invisible" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/full"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fullscreen"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/potrait"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_normal_screen"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/relative2">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/play_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@color/material_blue_grey_800"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:visibility="visible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and code for changing the orientation:

```
full.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            defaultScreenOrientationMode = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            defaultVideoViewParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) videoview.getLayoutParams();
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

            full.setVisibility(view.GONE);
            potrait.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            play_list.setVisibility(View.GONE);



            videoview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            //     mc.show(0);
                }
            }, 700);
        }
    });

    potrait.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int defaultScreenOrientationMode;
            potrait.setVisibility(view.INVISIBLE);
            full.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
           play_list.setVisibility(view.VISIBLE);
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);

            videoview.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    videoview.setLayoutParams(defaultVideoViewParams);
                    videoview.layout(10, 10, 10, 10);
                //    mc.show(0);
                }
            }, 700);
        }
    });
```

Comment: now i am able to set my video view to full screen in landscape mode by adding an xml in layout-land folder but now the problem is every time when i change the orientation video is loaded again i just want that video should be continued from the previous orientation

Answer (score 0):

To stop reloading activity on orientation change, write below code in manifest

```
<activity
    android:name=".YourActivityName"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

Comment: already used but when i use this piece of code in my manifest my xml of layout-land is not loaded and when i remove this orientation from manifest xml get loaded and video restart

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout layout = /* ... */;
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```